# Tricky JQuery update image href question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Alright so I don't know if it can be done, but with the great minds we have here on stackoverflow, I'm confident someone can point me in the right direction.

So I am looking to dynamically update the href tag for an image so when the user chooses a different product option (lets say a different scent) the image link will take the user to that scent's larger image file.

Here's the code so far:

```
$("#main-image").attr("href", $('.more-views ul li a img[alt="' + $select.find('option:selected')[0].getAttribute('product_id') + '"]').attr('src'));
```

So that's the easy part.  Now the tricky part is shaving down that url that the code gets.

Right now it only gets the smaller version of the image to populate the expanded view.
I need it to get the larger image.

This is the link for the larger image:
    http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64565-a.jpg

And here is the link for the smaller image:
     http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/370x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64565-a.jpg

notice how the smaller image has the 370x in the pathname.  Is there any way I can treat this as a string and filter this out??!  Keep in mind I need to use the .attr code from above.

Let the javascript geniuses to it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What mark-up do you have for this section of the page? I'm curious mostly because an `img` doesn't ***have*** an `href` attribute (it does have a `src` attribute, though).

Comment: I probably wasn't clear here.  I meant for the <a href> tag

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `.replace(/370x\//,'')` to `.attr('src')`

```
$("#main-image").attr("href",
                  $('.more-views ul li a img[alt="'
                         + $select.find('option:selected')[0].getAttribute('product_id')
                         + '"]')
                    .attr('src')
                    .replace(/370x\//,'') );
```

Comment: Wow thank you!  Proven to be much easier than I had originally thought.